# How do I flip a texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have a model (not built by me) where one of the materials is defined as shown by the image below. Occasionally I would like to flip the texture-image (sailor_right.png).

I thought I could connect a Mapping-node somewhere to do the flipping but I cant figure out how and where? So:

- What type of node should I connect?
- Where should I connect the node?
- What values should be used in the new node?

The point is that I'm using this model and driving it with python to apply different texture-images between renderings. I could of course flip it using some other program before feeding it to blender, but I think that would be inconvenient since I could just get blender to do it for me.

Obviously I'm fairly new to blender and 3D-modeling so please be kind to me. But I might be all wrong here in my assumptions, if so then tell me that!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a texture coordinates node and a mapping node.

Depending on what you mean by "flip" can change the scale to negative one for whatever axis, or rotate the coordinates 180 degrees on a particular axis.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On the UV Editing tab press <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> (Scale X-Axis -1) and the mapping will be flipped.